# Disable Apache log in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am doing a stand-alone website on a DVD using XAMPP, Apache service won't start because it access a read-only **error.log** (since XAMPP is already on the DVD). Same thing for MySQL when starting the service.

I have tried editing `httpd.conf` and commented the line `#ErrorLog "logs/error.log"` but still got the log file created in Apache. Is there another way to do it? I want also to stop accessing MySQL from using the log file.

Answer (score 0):

For apache, you need to comment out **both** the ErrorLog and CustomLog directives. If your xampp config uses vhosts, you also need to comment out the directives in the vhost definitions.

The mysql docs says logs can be enabled or disabled, you should follow the docs and change the server config accordingly: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html

Comment: I am using the default settings for Apache so I guess I am not using vhosts. I commented both ErrorLog and CustomLog in httpd.conf but it still access/modify `logs/error.log`